# PHP - A Better way to call $_POST Data?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Is there a better way to using post data rather then defining the variables manually?

**My Current Method**

```
<form method="POST" action="form.php">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    function echoname ($name) {

        echo $name;

    };

    echo "This is my new" . echoname ($name);

?>
```

Now I know you can just go like this for my example however it is *only an example*:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name']

        echo "This is my new" . $name;

?>
```

Is there a better way to use `$_POST['value']` without having to define the post data as a variable every time?

As a note, i have looked here: [PHP Manual $_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) already

Thanks!

Comment: There is a function called extract() that can turn all the named indexes in $_POST into individual variables, with an optional prefix to avoid naming collisions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: @FreemanLambda that page has a warning not to use with untrusted data...

Comment: @AaronHatton If you don't overwrite variables then nothing should happen. If you want to use `$_POST[anything]` then you'd obviously risk this as well?

Comment: It's generally discouraged to use superglobals explicitly within your code. If for any reason you wanted to rename the text input to say `lastname` it would require you to edit any references to `$_POST['name']`. It's much easier if you assign it to a variable with the appropriate scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use `extract()` for security purposes (even though you could simply skip variables that already exist), then you can simply loop through an array - check if the `$_POST` value exists, and if it does, create a variable of the key:

```
<?php
    $postVariablesToExtract = array("name", "password", "email");

    foreach ($postVariablesToExtract as $postVariableToExtract) {
        if (isset($_POST[$postVariableToExtract])) {
            $$postVariableToExtract = $_POST[$postVariableToExtract];
        } else {
            $$postVariableToExtract = null;
        }
    }

    var_dump($name); //null - as we don't have any POST values
    var_dump($password); //null - as we don't have any POST values
    var_dump($email); //null - as we don't have any POST values
?>
```

Comment: This way looks alot more complicated, but I guess it would make the injection checking quicker by filtering the array?

Comment: @AaronHatton `extract` is basically a function like this that creates variables based on keys. The only difference here is that we only set variables that we've already decided (so I can't change my username by posting `username=MyOwnUsernameVariable`).

Comment: are you able to post some php manual links for reference please?

Comment: The only thing you need a reference to here is the fact that by using `$$variable` it should be read as "*create a variable called $($variable)*", so if `$variable` is "foo", then it'd create a variable called `$foo`. [**Here's the manual for that**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

```
echo "This is my new" . $_POST['name'];
```

but, the better way is

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) // check if this data is exsit
    echo "This is my new" . $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use the variable directly i.e.:

```
echo "This is my new " . $_POST['name'];
```

However it's a good idea to check for emptiness (or validating in general). For example, in the case below, if the variable is empty I assign a default value:

```
$name = empty($_POST['name']) ? 'John' : $_POST['name'];
echo "This is my new $name";
```

Comment: use `isset` instead. `empty` would pick the default if the value was `""` or `0` which most likely isn't what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['value']` is already a variable so its not a must for you to store it in a variable. Then again, its common practice to store it in a variable before manipulating it.

Also, `$_POST` is an array. Which is why you need to specify the Key, in your case `['value']` is your key. Now you can also echo out the entire `$_POST` if you want to see other values it holds, but then echo does not work on arrays, so you will need to use `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what way you need it, but it might be important that $_POST is normal array, so you can use foreach function.

```
foreach ($_POST as $item) {
  print_r($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get post data but it depends the requirement in some instances.

- foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)     $body .= $key . ' -> ' .
  $value . '
  ';
- If posted data has no key, but only value, use Raw Post Data:

  $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
- You can use $_REQUEST as well as $_POST to reach everything such as Post, Get and Cookie data.
- You can also use simply $input_data = $_POST extract() may be
  useful for you.